# change kerning in ggplot geom_raster visualization

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am doing a matrix visualization of my data using ggplot + geom_raster, and it currently looks as follow:

```
ggplot(df,
       aes(diff_effect, affect_type, fill=affect_value)) +
       scale_fill_gradient2(low="red3", mid="white", high="royalblue3") +
       geom_raster() +
       geom_text(aes(label = round(affect_value, 1))) +
       scale_size_identity() +
       ylab("affect dimension") +
       xlab("condition")
```

[image: bad kerning on values]

I would like to change the kerning of the values in the matrix tiles.

I have tried:

```
ggplot(df,
       aes(diff_effect, affect_type, fill=affect_value)) +
       scale_fill_gradient2(low="red3", mid="white", high="royalblue3") +
       geom_raster() +
       geom_text(aes(label = round(affect_value, 1)), size=20) +
       ylab("affect dimension") +
       xlab("condition")
```

but that just uniformly scales every glyph
[image]

How do I adjust the kerning on this data?

For awareness, this is what the affect_value column looks like:

```
# A tibble: 96 x 1
   affect_value
          <dbl>
 1      -0.101 
 2      -0.338 
 3      -0.140 
 4       0.258 
 5      -0.146 
 6       0.420 
 7       0.172 
 8      -0.0537
 9      -0.440 
10      -0.164
```

Comment: I'm unsure what exactly the goal is, I can see a 4x4 cell grid and your tibble has 96 rows. So there are 16 values to plot per cell? Of course this is going to be overplotted, the `affect_value` as colour only shows the last entry per xy position.

Comment: ah I was under the impression ggplot summarized the data, my mistake, I must've misunderstood!